# Need mongo query to find service based on being active on server

Tags: mongodb

I have the following documents in mongo:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "env" : "pilot", 
    "service_name" : "test1", 
    "instances" : 
    [ 
        { 
        "location" : "server1", 
        "type" : "passive", 
        }, 
        { 
        "worker_location" : "server2", 
        "type" : "active" 
        } 
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : 2, 
    "env" : "pilot", 
    "service_name" : "test2", 
    "instances" : 
    [ 
        { 
        "worker_location" : "server1", 
        "type" : "active", 
        }, 
        { 
        "worker_location" : "server2", 
        "type" : "passive" 
        } 
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to setup a query to return the only the services that are active on certain servers.  So, if I want services that are only active on server2, I should get test1.  However, I'm still getting all the services regardless of what server they are on.

This is my query string so far:

```
db.service.find({"env":"pilot", "instances.worker_location":"server2", "instances.type":"active"}, {"service_name":1})
```

I expect to only get test1, but I get both services.  How would I go about doing this?

Edit:
I have also tried using the and operator:

```
db.service.find( {$and: [
{"instances.worker_location":"server2", 
"instances.type":"active"}] }, {"service_name":1})
```

With no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use the aggregation pipeline for this, specifically the `$unwind` operator, if you only want the matched instances. Although, I could be misunderstanding the question.

Consider the following ... ([live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gzelGUgDpOG))

#### Database

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "env": "pilot",
    "service_name": "test1",
    "instances": [
      {
        "location": "server1",
        "type": "passive",
        
      },
      {
        "worker_location": "server2",
        "type": "active"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "env": "pilot",
    "service_name": "test2",
    "instances": [
      {
        "worker_location": "server1",
        "type": "active",
        
      },
      {
        "worker_location": "server2",
        "type": "passive"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$instances"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          env: "pilot"
        },
        {
          "instances.type": "active"
        },
        {
          "instances.worker_location": "server2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      service_name: 1
    }
  }
])
```

#### Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "service_name": "test1"
  }
]
```